# underscore doesn't replace variables

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I have following line in js:

```
 terminalsListHtml += this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
```

I debug following code:

try to evaluate `_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj)`:
[image]

it looks good

but try to evaluate

```
this.compiled(_.extend(this.terminals[i], {clazz: 'all'}, obj));
```

[image]

It is not expected result for me.

Please help to fix described problem.

P.S.

```
window.MARC = {
        addTerminalPage: {
            ....
            compiled: _.template($('#terminal-template').text()),



<script type="text/template" id="terminal-template">
    <li data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" class="{{ clazz2 }}">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminal" class="{{ clazz }}" data-terminal-id="{{ id }}" />
            <a href="#" title="" class="image"><img
                    src="<c:url value='/resources/images/img1.png'/>"
                    alt=""/></a>

            <h3>{{ name }}
                <small>{{ place }}</small>
            </h3>
            <p>{{ description }}</p>

            <p class="count">Проходимость: <span>{{ count }}</span> чел./час</p>

            <p class="count">Стоимость: <span>{{ amount }}</span> руб./час</p>
        </label>
    </li>
</script>
```

P.S.

```
_.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim
    };
```

Comment: By default underscore templates use ERB syntax e.g. `<span><%= foobar %></span>`. Have you specified that you would like underscore to use mustache.js style `<span>{{ foobar }}</span>` templating? See the [template section of the underscore.js docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for info on how to enable this.

Comment: Have you updated `_.templateSettings` to use Handlebars syntax?

Comment: @mu is too short are you aboyt this  **_.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim
    };** ?

Comment: @mu is too short  your comment helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working after moving

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/gim,
        escape: /\{\{\-(.+?)\}\}/gim
    };
</script>
```

at the begining of file